# Problema ao pegar valor do textbox com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma function que precisa pegar o valor do textbox para realizar uma validação e se caso essa validação for true habilitar o datepicker.
Mas ao não está pegando valor do textbox.
Ao dar um alert no textbox, está mostrando "Undefined".
Como posso resolver ?

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#txtNovaDtVenc").datepicker("option", "disabled", true,  { changeMonth: true, changeYear: true }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
  $("#EscolhaData").hide();
  $('.a').click(function () {
    $("#EscolhaData").toggle();
    $('button').click(function () {
      var senha;    
      senha = $("txtSenha").val();    
      alert(senha);
      if (senha == "administrador") {
        $("#txtNovaDtVenc").datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        $("#LinhaSenha").hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="EscolhaData">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Nova dt. de vencimento :
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.TextBox("txtNovaDtVenc", "", new { @class = "form-control form-control-custom", style="width:100px" })
    </td>              
  </tr>
  <tr id="LinhaSenha">
    <td>
      Senha: 
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.TextBox("txtSenha", "", new { @class = "form-control form-control-custom", style="width:100px" })
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" value="Ok" style="width:30px; height:30px;"></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Como você esta dando o alerta?

Comment: Marque a pergunta como respondida...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu campo *SENHA* está assim:

`@Html.TextBox("txtSenha", "", new { @class = "form-control form-control-custom", style="width:100px" })`

Você não deu uma identificação individual para esse campo. Você pode acrescentar uma classe `.senha` ou um `@id = 'senha'`, por exemplo, e usar isso no seu seletor jQuery.

No seu jQuery você está fazendo assim:

`$("txtSenha").val();`

Mas não vai funcionar, porquê você não está chamando nada. É um seletor que não existe.

Faça isso. Nesse caso você está chamando o seletor com nome de campo senha.

`var senha = $("input[name='txtSenha']").val();`

Ou se você acrescentar a classe ou ID poderá chamar pelo seu seletor.

**Classe**

`var senha = $(".senha").val();`

ou **ID**

`var senha = $("#senha").val();`

Comment: Funcionou!! Obrigado.

Comment: Marque a resposta...

Answer (score 5):

Pra pegar o valor do textbox com jquery seria assim:

```
$("#txtSenha").val();
```